# Creating List using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, malloc

I want to create a linked list and keep two pointers. One for the head and one for the last element. I tried several approaches and just found a solution, but I don't know why my first solution don't work. The pointer in head->next  always points on the last element, instead of the correct one.

```
int main(void){ // first solution

    struct pointList *lastElement;
    struct pointList *head;
    struct pointList headHelp = {.next = NULL, .p.x = 5, .p.y = 5};
    head = &headHelp;
    int i = 0;
    lastElement = &headHelp;
    for( i = 8; i < 10; i++){
        printf("LastElement: %d/%d\n", lastElement->p.x, lastElement->p.y);
        struct pointList *helpPoint;
        helpPoint = ((struct pointList*) malloc(sizeof(struct pointList)));
        struct pointList newElement = *helpPoint;
        newElement.next = NULL;
        newElement.p.x = i;
        newElement.p.y = i;

        lastElement->next = &newElement;
        lastElement = &newElement;
    }
    //printList(head);
    printf("LastElement: %d/%d\n", lastElement->p.x, lastElement->p.y);
    printf("head -> next: %d/%d\n", head->next->p.x, head->next->p.y);
    printf("finish\n");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
LastElement: 5/5
LastElement: 8/8
LastElement: 9/9
head -> next: 9/9
finish
```

but it should be  :   head -> next: 8/8
So the "next" pointer of head is changed in every loop execution

The solution which works looks like this:

```
int main(void){

    struct pointList *lastElement;
    struct pointList *head;
    struct pointList headHelp = {.next = NULL, .p.x = 5, .p.y = 5};
    head = &headHelp;
    int i = 0;
    lastElement = &headHelp;
    for( i = 8; i < 10; i++){
        printf("LastElement: %d/%d\n", lastElement->p.x, lastElement->p.y);
        lastElement->next = ((struct pointList*) malloc(sizeof(struct pointList)));

        lastElement->next->next = NULL;
        lastElement->next->p.x = i;
        lastElement->next->p.y = i;

        lastElement = lastElement->next;
    }
    //printList(head);
    printf("LastElement: %d/%d\n", lastElement->p.x, lastElement->p.y);
    printf("head -> next: %d/%d\n", head->next->p.x, head->next->p.y);
    printf("finish\n");
    return 0;
}
```

used struct:

```
struct pointList {
    struct point p;
    struct pointList *prev;
};
```

Comment: offtopic: Why are you mixing dynamic (malloc) memory with local memory in list nodes?

Comment: This: `helpPoint = ((struct pointList*) malloc(sizeof(struct pointList)));` really should be `helpPoint = malloc(sizeof *helpPoint);`. Way shorter, easier to read, less risk of error, and just ... well, better. [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @Telijas  Should there be struct pointList *next instead of  struct pointList *prev; in the structure definition?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the first code snippet is that you take and use the pointer to a local variable. The variable `newElement` have its scope inside the loop only, so when the loop iterates the current `newElement` variable goes out of scope and you are left with a stray pointer. This leads to *undefined behavior*.

You also allocate memory for `helpPoint` but you don't actually use it (when you initialize `newElement` using `helpPoint` you initialize one uninitialized structure with another uninitialized structure), and you do not free it anywhere leading to memory leaks.